# stacked bar plot from loop not adding different components of bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this (column and row number can vary, which is why I need to define a function for plotting).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
plot_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'decl': [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000667, 0.000833, 0.000833, 0.000000],
  'dk': [0.003333, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.001333, 0.001667, 0.000000, 0.000000],
  'yes': [0.769167, 0.843333, 0.762000, 0.666000, 0.721667, 0.721667, 0.775833],
  'no': [0.227500, 0.156667, 0.238000, 0.332000, 0.275833, 0.277500, 0.224167]})
```

For this data, I would like to create a plot akin to the one created with this code for a static number:

```
# configure plot
N = len(plot_df) # number of groups
num_y_cats = len(plot_df.columns) # number of y-categories (responses)
ind = np.arange(N) # x locations for the groups
width = 0.35 # width of bars

p1 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,1], width)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,2], width)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,3], width)

plt.ylabel('[%]')
plt.title('Responses by country')

x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in plot_df.index])

plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)) # ticks from, to, steps
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]), ('decl', 'dk', 'yes', 'no'))
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following [plot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m14u5gjsdexy6pm/testplot.png?dl=0), which poses two issues I cannot overcome and seek help for:

1. The numbers don't add up to 1.0 - although they should, as I created the original `df` with a normalization (`plot_df['sum'] = plot_df['decl'] + plot_df['dk'] + plot_df['yes'] + plot_df['no']`).
2. The other issue is that I want to define a function creating the same plot for `df`s with a variable number of rows and columns but am stuck on the part creating the different plots. Thus far, I have:

   ```
   def bar_plot(plot_df):
   ''' input: data frame where rows are groups; columns are plot components to be stacked '''

   # configure plot
   N = len(plot_df) # number of groups
   num_y_cats = len(plot_df.columns) # number of y-categories (responses)
   ind = np.arange(N) # x locations for the groups
   width = 0.35 # width of bars

   for i in range(num_y_cats): # for every response in the number of responses, e.g. 'Yes', 'No' etc.
       p = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,i], width) # plot containing the response

   plt.ylabel('[%]')
   plt.title('Responses by group')

   x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in plot_df.index]) # create a tuple containing all [country] names

   plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
   plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)) # ticks from, to, steps
   plt.show()
   ```

However, the problem here is that the loop doesn't properly add the different layers, and I cannot figure out how to do it.
Could someone give me pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem number 1, if I understand you correctly is that the heigth of the bars is not 1 (i.e. the sum of all the fractions). Your code

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,1], width)
...
```

creates four bar plots, *all* *starting* *from* *0* (on the y-axis). What we want is for `p2` to start on top of `p1`, `p3` to start on top of `p2` and so on. To do this we can specify the `bottom` argument (which defaults to 0) in `plt.bar`. So,

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,1], width, bottom=plot_df.iloc[:,0])
...
```

for `p3` we want `bottom` to start on the sum of `plot_df.iloc[:,0]` and `plot_df.iloc[:,1]`. We can do this either explicitly or using `np.sum` like so `np.sum(plot_df.iloc[:,:i]`. The latter of course has the advantage that we can sum over an arbitrary number of columns (like you want in your function).

As for your function... I gave it a shot. You probably have to perfect it yourself

```
def bar_plot(plot_df):
    width = 0.35 # width of bars

    p_s = []
    p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width))
    for i in range(1,len(plot_df.columns)):
        p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,i], width,
                           bottom=np.sum(plot_df.iloc[:,:i], axis=1)))

    plt.ylabel('[%]')
    plt.title('Responses by country')

    x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in plot_df.index])

    plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)) # ticks from, to, steps
    plt.legend(p_s, plot_df.columns)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent, I somehow missed the `bottom` argument. And the function, after tweaking a tiny little bit, works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function provided by @mortysporty (all credit accordingly) can be tweaked to complete the desired task by just adding a few lines in the beginning that are referenced later:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def newest_bar_plot(plot_df):
    N = len(plot_df) # number of groups
    ind = np.arange(N) # x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35 # width of bars

    p_s = []
    p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,0], width))
    for i in range(1,len(plot_df.columns)):
        p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, plot_df.iloc[:,i], width,
                           bottom=np.sum(plot_df.iloc[:,:i], axis=1)))

    plt.ylabel('[%]')
    plt.title('Responses by country')

    x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in plot_df.index])

    plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)) # ticks from, to, steps
    plt.legend(p_s, plot_df.columns)
    plt.show()
```